# Group elements by month three by three

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this Standard SQL query:

```
WITH utils AS (
    SELECT
        today,
        month_lag,
        GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(today, INTERVAL month_lag MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 11 MONTH), DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(today, INTERVAL month_lag MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS months
    FROM (
        SELECT
            CURRENT_DATE() AS today,
            IF(EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE()) < 7, 2, 1) AS month_lag
    )
)

SELECT
    date,
    MAX(ndays) AS ndays,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) AS date,
        IFNULL(DATE_DIFF(date, prev_date, DAY), 186) AS ndays
    FROM (
        SELECT
            date,
            LAG(date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS prev_date
        FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`, utils
        WHERE
            DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) >= DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(today, INTERVAL 17+month_lag MONTH), MONTH)
            AND type = 'Departamento'
    ), utils
    WHERE DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(today, INTERVAL 11+month_lag MONTH), MONTH) AND DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(today, INTERVAL month_lag MONTH), MONTH)
)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

With the following output:

```
Row     date         ndays     count    
1       2020-10-01   36        119
2       2020-11-01   35        61
3       2020-12-01   26        39
4       2021-01-01   30        33
5       2021-04-01   89        163
6       2021-06-01   57        101
7       2021-09-01   90        88
```

You can simulate the output with:

```
SELECT '2020-10-01' AS date, 36 AS ndays, 119 AS count UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-11-01' AS date, 35 AS ndays, 61 AS count UNION ALL 
SELECT '2020-12-01' AS date, 26 AS ndays, 39 AS count UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-01-01' AS date, 30 AS ndays, 33 AS count UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-04-01' AS date, 89 AS ndays, 163 AS count UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-06-01' AS date, 57 AS ndays, 101 AS count UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-09-01' AS date, 90 AS ndays, 88 AS count
```

I am retreiving the entries of the last 12 months. I have already grouped and ordered them by month, but I need to also group them three by three according to the month. Moreover, as you can see in the output there are missing months, so I have created in my `utils` statement a truncated month array named `months` containing the months that should be considered. Groups need to be dynamics, so that if I am retrieving data from November 2020 to October 2021, groups should be `2020 November - January 2021`, `February 2021 - April 2021`, `May 2021 - July 2021` and `August 2021 - October 2021`.

This is the output of my `WITH` clause:

```
Row     today         month_lag     months  
1       2021-10-15    1             2020-10-01
                                    2020-11-01
                                    2020-12-01
                                    2021-01-01
                                    2021-02-01
                                    2021-03-01
                                    2021-04-01
                                    2021-05-01
                                    2021-06-01
                                    2021-07-01
                                    2021-08-01
                                    2021-09-01
```

For each group of three months I need to get:

- **Name of the group:** something like `2020 October - 2020 December`
- **Max of ndays in the group:** MAX(ndays)
- **Number of entries in that group:** SUM(count)
- **Number of days elapsed in that group:** to get the number of days of a month I usually use this sentence `32 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME_SUB(date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 31 DAY))`, so I need the sum of that for each month of the group.

Considering all mentioned above, the output should be:

```
Row     group_name                        ndays     count     group_ndays
1       '2020 October - 2020 December'    36        219       92
2       '2020 January - 2020 March'       30        39        90
3       '2020 April - 2020 June'          89        196       91
4       '2020 July - 2020 September'      90        88        92
```

What would be the way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the months composing each group to change according to the input ... The month to start with is the first element in my months array at the utils

```
select 
  format_date('%Y %B', min(month)) || ' - ' || format_date('%Y %B',  max(month)) as group_name,
  max(ndays) as ndays,
  sum(count) as count,
  date_diff(last_day(max(month)) + 1, min(month), day) as group_ndays
from (
  select month, ndays, count,
    div(row_number() over(order by month) - 1, 3) grp
  from utils, unnest(months) month
  left join current_output
  on date = month
)
group by grp
```

if to apply to sample data in your question

```
WITH utils AS (
    SELECT
        today,
        month_lag,
        GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(today, INTERVAL month_lag MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 11 MONTH), DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(today, INTERVAL month_lag MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS months
    FROM (
        SELECT
            CURRENT_DATE() AS today,
            IF(EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE()) < 7, 2, 1) AS month_lag
    )
), current_output as (
  SELECT date '2020-10-01' AS date, 36 AS ndays, 119 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-11-01' AS date, 35 AS ndays, 61 AS count UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2020-12-01' AS date, 26 AS ndays, 39 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2021-01-01' AS date, 30 AS ndays, 33 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2021-04-01' AS date, 89 AS ndays, 163 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2021-06-01' AS date, 57 AS ndays, 101 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2021-09-01' AS date, 90 AS ndays, 88 AS count
)
```

the output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that perfectly fits my use case. Sorry again for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  any_value(format_date('%Y %B', first_day) || ' - ' || format_date('%Y %B', last_day)) as group_name,
  max(ndays) as ndays,
  sum(count) as count,
  any_value(date_diff(last_day + 1, first_day, day)) as group_ndays
from current_output, unnest([struct(
  date_trunc(date(date), quarter) as first_day,
  last_day(date(date), quarter) as last_day
)])
group by first_day
```

if applied to sample data in your question -

```
with current_output as (
  SELECT '2020-10-01' AS date, 36 AS ndays, 119 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-11-01' AS date, 35 AS ndays, 61 AS count UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2020-12-01' AS date, 26 AS ndays, 39 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2021-01-01' AS date, 30 AS ndays, 33 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2021-04-01' AS date, 89 AS ndays, 163 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2021-06-01' AS date, 57 AS ndays, 101 AS count UNION ALL
  SELECT '2021-09-01' AS date, 90 AS ndays, 88 AS count
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This will work if I were considering natural groups of three months. However, I need the months composing each group to change according to the input, that's why I created the `months` array in my `utils` statement. For example, if my year retrieved is from November 2020 to October 2021, I need the groups to be `2020 November - 2021 January`, `2021 February - 2021 April`, `2021 May - 2021 July` and  `2021 August - 2021 October`. How should I update the query you performed?

Comment: it is bad practice to change the question after answer already given - this obviously invalidates this answer. in such cases I would recommend rather stick with original question and post new one with that is better represents your real use case  :o) just suggestion

Comment: meantime - how to know which month to start with?

Comment: Sorry, I thought my needs were clear enough with the original question. I only edited it to add aditional information so that future lecturers would not make the same assumptions. The month to start with is the first element in my `months` array at the `utils` statement. It is calculated using the current date and a `month_lag` element, which depends on the current day of the month. Check the `utils` statement for a code explanation, as I don't know if I explained myself properly

Comment: ok. I see - will check shortly